# Store ID and Text

Tags: asp.net, html

How can I set some text to a label but also store its ID.  For instance I'm taking an ID/text value pair and painting the text in a label but I need to store the ID somewhere to be able to retrieve both that text value and ID later on for some more logic in the page.

I don't think you can store an ID in a label...which is what I'm using.  I can append html() to the label using jquery's html() function but then I do not know if this is a good html control to be using as I can't store the ID anywhere.

It is probably obvious what my choices are but honestly I've never come across this issue before.  I thought I could use an asp.net literal but I don't think that's gonna help me either with storing the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using jQuery,you can use [`jQuery.data();`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) for this. And if you are using HTML5 , you can use client side storage.

Answer (score 2):

When I'm required to do this, e.g. inside a `Repeater`, I solved this storing the ID inside an  additional [hidden field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx).

This enabled me to later retrieve the ID back, e.g. after a postback or through JavaScript in the client.

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.value.aspx) for a description of the `Value` property as well as an example that deals with JavaScript and postback.

Comment: I thought about this but was wondering if there was just a cleaner way than having to use 2 controls..elements.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict Yes, I thought that, too, but since time was/is short, I used this since years and never regret until now :-)

Comment: yea it's not that bad....I mean really that's probably the norm, just hold it in a hidden field OR session state object... but I figured there had to be something like a one stepper, and just found out about the jQuery .dada().

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options to store your ID:

1. Session Variable
2. ViewState
3. HiddenField

Comment: good answer, but I went to jquery route for the final answer..with I could have chosen both but I'm already using jquery to populate the elements so it naturally fit with my code already....easy and quick.

Comment: I don't use Viewstate for performance reasons.  I usually code for .coms and it's a no-no :).  So I'm not to fond of viewstate and I do not ever view it as an object I am willing to use.  Custom session objects, asp.net session objects, or hidden field fine..but nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options.

1. Convert the value to a string and store the value in a [`HiddenField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx).
2. Store the value in the [`Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx).
3. Store the value in the [`ViewState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate.aspx).